# List of database in Analysis service

Tags: c#, ssas

I want to get list of all databases in both Process and Tabular instance using `Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient` and **not with** `Microsoft.AnalysisServices`

This is because I am compelled to use .Net 3.5 and cannot work with .Net 4.0.

There are commands to get the data using SQL Server Management Studio:

```
SELECT [CATALOG_NAME] FROM $system.dbschema_catalogs

SELECT * from $system.dbschema_tables
```

But I want to execute these to get list of Databases. I need to connect *without specifying Initial Catalog*.

---

I have also tried connecting using `Microsoft.AnalysisServices`;

```
Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server amoconn = new
Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server();

String connstring = "Data Source = MyServerName;";
amoconn.Connect(connectionString);// I get "A connection cannot be made. Ensure that the server is running." error here 
Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Database db = amoconn.Databases.FindByName(amoconn.ConnectionInfo.Catalog);
```

Can anyone how to connect to server without requiring to provide Catalog/Database name?

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with ASP.NET

Comment: When I used Microsoft.AnalysisServices 10.0.0.0, I was able to compile and run under .NET 3.5. Depends on what version of SQL Server you need to connect to, I will bet. This works for SQL 2008 R2.

Comment: I am working on SQL server 2012.. I am able add reference to AnalysisServices on .Net 3.5.. But the issue is "amoconn.Connect(connectionString);" fails no matter what connection string I provide..